# docker-compose container lose index path settings

Tags: docker, indexing, path, docker-compose, couchbase

I have this docker-compose file

```
services:
  couchbase-node-01:
  image: couchbase:community-6.5.0
  container_name: couchbase-node-01
  volumes:
    - /var/docker/couchbase/data:/data:z
    - /var/docker/couchbase/index:/index:z
    - /var/docker/couchbase/settings:/opt/couchbase/var:z
  ports:
    - 8091:8091
```

After run "docker-compose up -d" I setup new cluster with this settings

[image: couchbase settings]

So in the web console there is this

[image: path settings ok]

after this, I do "docker-compose down" and it destroys the container, and after I run again "docker-compose up -d".
And now, when I go to web console, there is this

[image: path settings ko]

where Couchbase saves the path of data and index?

Comment: What is the `:z` at the end of your volume mounts? I've never seen that before.

Comment: You can read doc here https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label